# How to check String Contains Alphabets or Digits-Regular Expression c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How to check Whether string contains Alphabets or Digits using Regular Expression.
In a single regular expression How can i achieve this in c#.Currently i am finding alphabets like this

```
 Regex.Matches(folderPath, @"[a-zA-Z]").Count
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Whether string contains Alphabets or Digits

For this case:

```
Regex.Matches(folderPath, @"[a-zA-Z0-9]").Count
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you do not need regex to check if there are digits or alphabetic characters. Use LINQ with [`Char.IsLetterOrDigit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletterordigit(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var hasAlphanum = "!?A1".Any(p => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(p)); // => true
var hasAlphanum1 = "!?1".Any(p => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(p)); // => true
var hasAlphanum2 = "!?".Any(p => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(p));  // => false
```

The `.Any(p => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(p))` part is checking if any character inside the string conforms to the condition inside the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
string folderPath = "abc123";
Regex.IsMatch(folderPath, @"[a-zA-Z0-9]") // returns true
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/faeZND